# How to add language, platform and project type data to custom template in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a extension which adds custom project template which is displayed under Installed -> Visual C# -> < type> in visual studio 2017.

but when i am using same extension in Visual studio 2019, on searching i get the template but without any label  (like language, platform and project type).

and even if i select language filter in the wizard, i don't see the template in C#.

if any one can help, how to add language, platform, project type tag to the template.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a VS 2019 issue. It has now been solved in visual studio 2019 version 16.1 Preview 2. However it has no backwards compatibility with previous visual studio versions.

For more information about the bug see: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/422666/allow-custom-project-templates-for-custom-language.html

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/template-tags?view=vs-2019 for adding tags in visual studio 2019 Version > version 16.1 preview 2.